# Как скомпилировать scss в css в laravel(vite.config.js)

Tags: html, reactjs, node.js, laravel

В файле `vite.config.js` имеется следующее:

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                'resources/scss/app.scss',
                'resources/js/app.js',
            ],
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ],
});
```

При запуске `npm run dev`, scss файл должен быть скомпилирован в css файл папке public, но к сожалению ничего не появляется в папке public.

Как решить данную проблему?

Comment: В head скриптах должно быть прописано `@vite(['resources/scss/app.scss', 'resources/js/app.js'])` и у меня в public/build файл компилится